# Django admin, section without "model"?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

in the Django administration console, all section (menu links) come from models with database tables, but what would I need to do if I need a section without a corresponding model object (no database table) that fetches data from other section with model?

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: "model (no database table) that bring me data from other section with model"?  This isn't very clear.  Can you provide a more complete definition of what you are talking about?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for reply, well like Thierry said i want an admin uls with my owen view but this url dont have any model relation.. is just a link where a want to show the data from x database table... sorry my english :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you want to add new admin urls with your own customized views and template: [django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls)

You can construct those new admins without a new model this way.

Comment: Isn't this only an option if you *are* using a model for the page? The question is about not using a model.

Answer (score -4):

I did it with [Proxy Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)....

Comment: Could you explain how?

Comment: ProxyModel doesnt make sense to use here. It is misleading.

Comment: (I'm using Django 3.0) In fact you can use proxy models to achieve that. You can create a proxy model on any model of your app, and register it with a ModelAdmin. Then the proxy model will show up in the admin dashboard as a normal model. Afterwards you have to overwrite the views (changelist_view, add_view, change_view, delete_view) to do whatever you want as you won't want to work on the proxied model. But it is a very hacky way to get something into the admin interface, which you normally not want to.